# ViewController_iPad.xib vs ViewController~ipad.xib

Tags: ios, xcode, naming-conventions, xib

I am working on a tutorial and something interesting caught my attention. I just created a Single View Application Project and I noticed two .xib files, one named `ViewController_iPhone.xib`, one named `ViewController_iPad.xib`. In my projects, if I wanted different .xibs for iPhone and iPad I would use `ViewController.xib` for iPhone and `ViewController~ipad.xib` for iPad. I kind of understand that this may be a new naming convention, but can I use this naming convention event if I target older iOS versions?
Also this happens in xCode 4.6

Thank you.

Comment: Actually I don't think this is a new naming convention. I just looked in the AppDelegate.m and found out that it checks for the device type, and loads the appropriate .xib file, which is pretty stupid to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Think you might have come across universal applications on iOS , or might loading .xib files according to the device . Either way you should use `~ipad` instead of `~iPad` and `~iphone` instead of
`~iPhone` for it to work correctly.

Both will work alike on simulator but the prior will ditch on device.

PLease Find the extract from Apple reference for [iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH1-SW2)

iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources

In iOS 4.0 and later, it is possible to mark individual resource files as usable only on a specific type of device. This capability simplifies the code you have to write for Universal applications. Rather than creating separate code paths to load one version of a resource file for iPhone and a different version of the file for iPad, you can let the bundle-loading routines choose the correct file. All you have to do is name your resource files appropriately.

To associate a resource file with a particular device, you add a custom modifier string to its filename. The inclusion of this modifier string yields filenames with the following format:

.

The  string represents the original name of the resource file. It also represents the name you use when accessing the file from your code. Similarly, the  string is the standard filename extension used to identify the type of the file. The  string is a case-sensitive string that can be one of the following values:

```
~ipad - The resource should be loaded on iPad devices only.

~iphone - The resource should be loaded on iPhone or iPod touch devices only.
```